# Data path "/fileReplacements/1/replace" must match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$". angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-builder

I updated the angular from 10 to 14 and in the build i was using `fileReplacements` for favicon.ico replacement like this

```
"fileReplacements": [
     {
        "replace": "src/favicon.ico",
        "with": "src/images/my/favicon.ico"
     }
],
```

but this is showing error

```
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1" must have required property 'src'.
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1/replace" must match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

i tried in `assets` like this

```
"assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/web.config",
      "src/manifest.json",
      {
        "input": "src/favicon.ico",
        "output": "src/images/my/favicon.ico",
        "glob": "*.ico"
      },
      {
         "glob": "**/*",
         "input": "src/images/my",
         "output": "assets/images"
      }
   ]
```

but this shows

```
✖ Copying of assets failed.
Unable to copy assets: ENOTDIR invalid cwd E:/PROJECTS/myproj/src/favicon.ico
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: what is set in `sourceRoot` of your angular.json?

Comment: `"sourceRoot": "src",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every environment, i have created a separate folder under builds like this
In the assets in angular.json

```
{
   "glob": "**/*",
   "input": "src/build/images-prod1",
   "output": "assets/images"
}
```

so in `images-prod1` there is differnt favico file that will be copied in assets/images

and in my index.html

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
```

so assets will copy different file based on build config and path is same